# Nuxt build - fail to add web component dependency

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have a monorepo with stencil web components and  vue wrapper components offered by Stencil  using VueOutputTarget.
The component works fine in dev mode but when I run build mode it complaints about entry file not found.

I observed that these are included in dev mode but not in build mode.

> hello.oqCrayH6.js:1 TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/my-component.entry.js undefined
>
> URL -

[https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/paragdiwan/nuxt-stencil-integration](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/paragdiwan/nuxt-stencil-integration)

**please run**

> pnpm nuxt-dev. ( works --> will be able to see text containing "hello
> world" from stencil component. pnpm build  ( throws error)
>
> URL: -localhost:3000/hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing further, got to know that `vite has difficulties in loading stencil components lazily`

Reference URL = https://stenciljs.com/docs/config-extras
see attribute stencil provides - **enableImportInjection**

but perhaps, `vite` needs to check on this.